# Vue Router - How to pass along query params between routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following scenario...

When a user visits the route `/intended/page`, they are redirected to another route, say `/foo/page?next=/intended/page`. I add a query param `next=/intended/page` to keep the original route. From the redirect route, the user goes through a series of other pages/components , say `/bar/page` then `/baz/page` at the end of which I want to take them to the original route. The problem is how to pass along next to bar and baz routes. I figure I could store the query param in Vuex but maybe there is a simpler way using vue router. I tried doing it in a global guard

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (from.query.next) next({path: to.path, query: {next: from.query.next}});
    else next();
});
```

but I end up in an infinite loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit querystring parameters runtime, before each route, you just need to edit your **to.query** object:

**example:**

```
to.query.site = 'mysite';
```

**and then:**

```
next({path: to.path, query: to.query})
```

If your url was: /#/?name=Gianni
It will redirect to: /#/?name=Gianni&site=mysite